# Robust standard errors for a time series regression

Tags: time-series, references, asymptotics, robust-standard-error, overlapping-data

Suppose we have time series data $(p_t, (x_{i,t})_{i = 1...n})$, where $p_t$ is a price and $x_{i,t} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ regressors. From $p_t$ we construct $r_t = \frac{p_{t+30}}{p_t} -1$, the one-month ahead returns. Consider the regression

$$
r_t = \sum \beta_i x_{i, t-1} + \epsilon_t.
$$

**Question**: If I am willing to assume the usual general regularity conditions on $(p_t, (x_{i,t})_{i = 1...n})$ (e.g. existence of sufficiently many moments, mixingale at a suffcient mixing rate, etc.), then the same holds for 
$(r_t, (x_{i,t})_{i = 1...n})$. Therefore one can compute the robust standard errors in the usual way a la Newey-West, correct? If not, what is different in this "rolling window" kind of situation? In the latter case, I am looking for a reference (probably from the econometrics literature but statistics reference are just fine too).

Comment: Would the [tag:overlapping-observations] tag be relevant here? My favourite treatment of overlapping observations is one found in Hayashi's textbook "Econometrics".

Comment: Yes, tag added. Thank you.